# SQLite database update

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

### Problem Description

I have SQLite database in which I have keep two tables, In first Table `Companies` I keep company `ID` which is unique for that company, `Name` of company, `Websites` and `Emails`. Every company can have several addresses, so I create second Table `Addresses` and keep there company ID which is not unique in this case and other information.

#### For Example:

If in `Companies` table I have record like this

> 7785413   MyComp   http://www.mycomp.com   mycomp@email.com

In the `Addresses` table I can have records like this

> 7785413    0    Address1   +64841518549    +9985212848
>
> 7785413    1    Address2   +64841542359    +9985212848

As there is no unique columns in my second Table, I want to know how I can update records?
In first case I call

`database.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);`

function and if my IDs are same function throws an exception I catch it and update record. I can't do same thing in second Table as there is no unique columns and function will not throw an exception. Which is the best way to do that ?

### Tables

`CREATE TABLE Companies (ID TEXT UNIQUE, Name TEXT, Websites TEXT, Emails TEXT)`

`CREATE TABLE Addresses (ID TEXT, Position NUMERIC, Address TEXT, Tel TEXT, Mob TEXT)`

Comment: Can you not create a foreign key?

Comment: sorry ? what does you mean saying foreign ?

Comment: Simplistically, its a PK which extends over to a second table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: sorry as I am not native with sqlite can you please bring an example of how I can do that for my case ?

Comment: It is not a SQLite concept, but a vital part of relational databases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the primary key as a constraint on table creation.

`CREATE TABLE Addresses(ID TEXT, Position NUMERIC, Address TEXT, Tel TEXT, Mob TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (ID , Position ));`